# Extract certain words from string using Tcl or REgExpr

Tags: regex, tcl

Hi, I am trying to extract an engine from a String, which has proven my test (hold). In the example bellow, my output should be proengine2.

`engine1 {status fail reason checked depth 0 } engine2 {status fail reason checked depth 0 } 
proengine1 {status open reason checked depth 0 } **proengine2** {status **hold** reason checked depth 1 }`

Any idea how to do that with Tcl or regular expression?

Thanks,
Sasa

Comment: what did you try yet ?

Comment: FYI: The official documentation for the [Tcl `regexp` command](http://wiki.tcl.tk/986) and its [manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm), are found in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), listed under "Flavor-Specific Information". Once you are ready, you can try it out in one of the online regex testers, as listed in the bottom section.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the engine with status `hold`, try something like this:

```
regexp -- {([^\}[:blank:]]+?)\s*?\{status hold} $data - engine
```

Your engine will be in the `$engine` variable.

`([^\}[:blank:]]+?)` will match non `}` or blank characters (this is where the engine name is matched) and stored into the first submatch, `engine`, provided the next parts match, meaning any spaces `\s*?` and `{status hold`.

If you have multiple engines you might try something like that:

```
set engines [regexp -all -inline -- {[^\}[:blank:]]+?(?=\s*?\{status hold)} $data]
```

Where `$engines` will be a list of all engines on `hold`.

Here, I'm using a positive lookahead instead of capture groups because `-all -inline` will return a list of all matches and sub-matches. The regex is about the same, with the first pair of `()` removed and the second part wrapped around `(?= ... )` (which is the positive lookahead).

Answer (score 0):

Hi there here is a solution if the one with the `**hold**` always have the stars around as hold. Here is the code :

```
    String test = "engine1 {status fail reason checked depth 0 } engine2 {status fail reason checked depth 0 } proengine1 {status open reason checked depth 0 } **proengine2** {status **hold** reason checked depth 1 }";
    System.out.println(test.replaceAll(".*\\}\\s\\*{2}(.*)\\*{2}\\s\\{.*", "$1"));
```

output : `proengine2`

Comment: Thanks!!!In my tool with Tcl interpreter I got:

extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"regexp System.out.println(test.replaceAll(".*\\}\\s\\*{2}(.*)\\*{2}\\s\\{.*", "$1")"

Where did you test this?

Comment: I tested this in Java if it's the question ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your data is fortunately formatted like a Tcl dictionary, so:

```
set s {
engine1 {status fail reason checked depth 0 } engine2 {status fail reason checked depth 0 } 
proengine1 {status open reason checked depth 0 } proengine2 {status hold reason checked depth 1 }
}

set d [dict create {*}$s]
dict for {key info} $d {
    if {[dict get $info status] eq "hold"} {
        puts $key
    }
}
```

outputs

```
proengine2
```

http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/dict.htm